# passing rvalue raises cannot bind to lvalue

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

The program is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename F, typename T1, typename T2>
void flip2(F f, T1 &&t1, T2 &&t2)
{
      f(t2, t1);
}

void g(int &&i, int &j)
{
      cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
      int i = 1;
      flip2(g, i, 42);
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error: rvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int'
```

But to my understanding, as `T2` is instantiated with `int`, then the type of `t2` is `int&&`, so it should be allowed to pass to function `g`'s first argument (`int &&`).

What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f(t2, t1);
```

`t2` has a name, so it is an lvalue. It's *type* is rvalue, but in an expression it's type is an lvalue. In order to pass it as an rvalue reference, you need to use `std::forward` (`move` or casting would be inappropriate here, because T1 and T2 are actually **universal references**, **not rvalue references**, see edit).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename F, typename T1, typename T2>
void flip2(F f, T1 &&t1, T2 &&t2)
{
      f(std::forward<T2>(t2), std::forward<T1>(t1));
}

void g(int &&i, int &j)
{
      cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
      int i = 1;
        flip2(g, i, 42);
}
```

http://ideone.com/Aop2aJ

### Why

Consider:

```
template<typename T>
void printAndLog(T&& text) {
    print(text);
    log(text);
}

int main() {
    printAndLog(std::string("hello, world!\n"));
}
```

When you use a variable's name, the expression-type is lvalue (glvalue?); the rvalueness is discarded. Otherwise in the example above, we'd have lost `text` to `print()`. Instead, we have to be explicit when we want to our rvalue to behave like one:

```
template<typename T>
void printAndLog(T&& text) {
    print(text);
    log(std::forward<T>(text));  // if text is an rvalue, give it up.
}
```

### Edit

I used `std::forward` because `T1&&` and `T2&&` are universal references, not rvalue references. https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: I don't understand why t2 is lvalue, the type of t2 is `int &&`, which seems like a rvalue reference.

Comment: @Charles0429 t2 has a name, you can take its address, so, it is an lvalue. The fact that it can bind to rvalue does not means it is an rvalue

Comment: @Amadeus How can you take an address of an (l- or r-value) reference? You'll end up with the address of the pointed-to object instead